# BJT output characteristics in negative Vce region?

Tags: bjt

How do the BJT output characteristics in negative Vce region look like? Is it zero current or a reflection of the usual characteriscs in positive Vce region about origin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it zero current or a reflection

It is not zero and also not a reflection. You can simulate this for specific models like this:

[image]

Which leads to these curves:

[image]

Zooming in the reverse region, for a wider range of base currents (logarithmically from 1uA to 1 mA):

[image]

Comment: So it indeed looks like a reflection about the origin?

Comment: At https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bipolar_junction_transistor you can see that the asymmetries in the BJT construction are responsible for the large differences in the Ic/Ib ratio. But there are similarities (2 PN junctions), which also reflect the in curves. The behavior is too different in magnitude, for me, to consider it as a reflection.

Comment: may I ask why the reverse characteristics are never used or mentioned in the text books?

Comment: It is rare. Sedra does mention it very briefly a few times. Also rare are the discrete applications, since the BJTs are optimized to work in the opposite quadrant. Take a look at the input stage of TTL circuits. You can connect the inputs to both voltage rails without damaging the circuit, using the reverse active mode in one level. I've also heard, but never seen a discrete implementation, of using the lower saturation voltage of the reverse configuration for switching (like in charge pumps).

Comment: BJTs used to be used as analog multiplexors.